# SQL CLR, HttpWebRequest, and Connection Throttling

Tags: sql-server-2008, httpwebrequest, .net-2.0, clr, windows-server-2008

Good day!

I have inherited a fairly complex MSSQL database. Used within the code are CLR Assembly DLLs that are called from within stored procedures.

Within these CLR Assembly DLLs, we are reaching out to a 3rd party web service via the .Net 2.0 HttpWebRequest object from the SQL server. (While I understand that this is not the appropriate way to do this, please keep in mind that this was inherited and we are in the process of fixing this.)

Here is the quandary we are currently experiencing:

The SQL CLR is currently throttled to two (2) outbound communication threads (as verified by netstat).

**Is there any way to increase the number of outbound threads from the SQL server, either via the .Net configurations or by some other method, including altering the assembly?**

Items attempted already:

- IIS Worker Thread increase
- Machine.Config:

  - processModel tuning
  - httpRuntime tuning
  - system.net connectionManagement tuning

However, no matter what changes are done in the .Net configuration or in IIS, I cannot increase the number of outbound threads. I've spent hours Google'ing the internets to try to find an answer as it relates to HttpWebRequests, SQL CLR, Assemblies, permission types, anything that can help...

Some other stats you may request:

- Code written in .NET Version 2.0
- SQL Server 2008 R2 EE
- Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5
- sp_configure clr_enabled = true
- Assembly / SP set to EXTERNAL_ACCESS
- SP was built WITH ENCRYPTION

Thank you in advance for any information you might be able to provide. If you need anything else, please feel free to ask.

J.R.

Answer (score 4):

This was solved using code, specifically the:

- ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(); and
- ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit.

These two lines needed to be added to the CLR and then the assembly rebuilt on the SQL server.

Hope this helps someone later on in the future.

J.R.